# Is it safe to upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to latest LTS version with working web-applications running in production?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, docker, lts

Is it safe to upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to latest LTS version with working web-applications running in production? I understand that there will be a need on smth like all processes should be stopped and alike stuff. I mean if not talking on dependencies, is there smth else that can prevent say docker from working? And so, is it a good practice at all?

Comment: You seem to be asking "*what could possibly go wrong?*"

Comment: It's never safe to upgrade production servers - that's why you have redundancy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several risks you run. Just to name 2: you say web applications so I assume a web server and a database are present. What if there is a setting that is deprecated that you are still using? Finding that issue and solving it might take a long time. I doubt there is (since I have been upgrading google cloud instances from 16.04/18.04 to 20.04 for 5 months) but there will be more situations like this.

edit: I have a real life example. The date format in MySQL has gotten an update.
A compare with a date "2000-00-00" is still valid but "2000-01" is no longer allowed. You must have mm and dd in a date where in older version this was warned about but now is mandatory. The ! in future release will also be removed from MySQL (we must use NOT).

So no, it is never safe to do anything like that on a production server. Even with backups. A simple power cut could be fatal. The downtime could then run into several hours.

The way to do this could be ...

1. Get a 2nd server and set it up. Install a backup of the production server onto that server.
2. Test 2nd server until satisfied.
3. Make 2nd server production server.
4. Make old production server 2nd server.
5. Rinse, repeat for the next upgrade.

I do understand that it is not always possible to have a backup system.

So another method could be to clone your system onto an external disk and then do the upgrade. If the upgrade goes wrong you clone the contents of the external disk back to your system. That makes it certain you can restore your currently working situation in the least amount of time.

Whatever method you choose: don't just upgrade. Prepare For Failure.

Comment: It isn't safe even going from 16.04 to 18.04.  For the one and only time, I crashed a production laptop taking a 16.04 system to 18.04 by simply allowing the software updater to perform an upgrade.  I had to reinstall 16.04 from scratch.  I now use a cheap second system for checking out the next level.  When satisfied, I 'brain transplant' to the production system by swapping the two harddrives.